# tracing through bitwise & and ^ in C

Tags: c, logic, bit-manipulation

I've been trying to trace through a function someone wrote for practice but I can't seem to get the right answer.

bitParity - returns 1 if x contains an odd number of 0's
Examples: bitParity(5) = 0, bitParity(7) = 1

```
int bitParity(int x) {

x = (x >> 16) ^ x;
x = (x >> 8) ^ x;
x = (x >> 4) ^ x;
x = (x >> 2) ^ x;
x = (x >> 1) ^ x;
return x&1;
}
```

So let's take 5 as example. 5 in Binary is 0101, which has an even number of 0s, so it should return 0.

Because everything before x>>2 will simply return 0101, I started with the line x = (x>>2)^x

```
(x>>2) = 0001 

(x>>2) ^ x = 0001 XOR 0101 = 0100
```

x is now 0100

I then compute x = (x>>1) ^ x

```
(x>>1) = 0010
(x>>1) ^ x = 0010 XOR 0100 = 0110
```

x is now 0110

I then return (x&1), which is (0110 & 1111) = 0110

If I understand everything correctly, bitParity should return all 0s if there is an even number of 0s, like this case of x = 5. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, most systems have a bit-counting instruction, which may be exposed by your compiler as a "popcount" intrinsic function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is correct till the last step `x & 1` interpretation is wrong.

According to your example `x = 0110` (after initial computations) and 1 is represented as  `0000 0000 0000 0001` (not 1111)

so `x & 1`

```
0110 
0001
----
0000
----
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, this algorithm is halving the number of bits that need to be analyzed with every step. If you have a 32 bit number, you compare the highest and lowest 16 bits. If both bits in a given position are set to 1, they keep the parity at zero. Only when the bits at a given position are different do the results need to be analyzed further. This is exactly what the bitwise XOR operator does.

Once the result has been reduced to one bit, that bit is the answer. The only error in your analysis is that `x & 1` in the last step is `0110 & 0001 == 0`, not `0110 & 1111 != 0`.